# Laravel - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use lightpick datepicker on my application. Unfortunately this works when I don't follow standards, and doesn't work when I do. 
**Blade :**

```
@section('page_script')
    <script src="{{ url('js/themeFiles/moment/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/themeFiles/lightpick/lightpick.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/custom/datePicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/custom/planningStats.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('planning.partials.planningStatsForm')
@endsection
```

**datePicker.js:**

```
var picker = new Lightpick({
    field: document.getElementById('ddebut_picker'),
    secondField: document.getElementById('dfin_picker'),
    repick: true,
    lang: 'fr',
    singleDate: false,
    selectForward: true
});
```

Error (if I use the above code) :
[image]

If I use the script tags inside `@section('content')` and do no use separate `@section('page_script')` section then everything works perfectly. But for the current code, it doesn't work. I haven't changed anything in the js, controller, blade or model.

Comment: after the page load, have you checked that scripts are loading well?

Comment: try simple script tag in content section `<script></script>`

Comment: Thank you @MiteshRathod. The scripts are loading properly. but the order was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @FaizanAli, I had to make scripts work using `page_script` section

Comment: @AmanDevrath, will you give upvote in my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

My JS was not able to find the elements, as my order was incorrect (even when it was correct when I checked the page source. Confusing though.).
I used `defer` attribute to solve my issue.

> [defer, a Boolean attribute,] is set to indicate to a browser that the
> script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but
> before firing DOMContentLoaded.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/8436087), **order matters**. There are other ways to solve the issue but I found `defer` to be most useful for external scripts.

```
@section('page_script')
    <script src="{{ url('js/themeFiles/moment/moment.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/themeFiles/moment/moment.min.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/themeFiles/lightpick/lightpick.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/custom/datePicker.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/custom/planningStats.js') }}" defer></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Also works with defer.  +1upvote from me!

Answer (score 1):

It deepens where the page_scripts in your layout included. I think in the head. Search in your code for @stack('page_script').

You can add in your Layout a section above the closing body. `@stack('custom_scripts')`. Then would be work if you "follow standard".
Change only the name from page_script to `@section('custom_script')`.

Comment: can you explain what does `@stack` does? is it any different than `@section('page_script')` ?

Comment: Namaste @AmanDevrath ! Yes of course. Stack reserves the space for scripts or code blocks pushed by a child layout. "Stack directive as self-explaining it stacks the scripts where you want to stack them." https://dev.to/abrardev99/how-to-use-laravel-blade-stack-scripts-2752

Comment: @AmanDevrath With stack you can order your script loading. But your solution to do it with defer it is also a good approach.

Comment: @AmanDevrath You understood?

Comment: yes. understood perfectly. Thank you so much. I'll try this approach once. Upvoted.

Comment: @AmanDevrath धन्यवाद

Comment: @MailLowrey Danke schön

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241348/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-aman-devrath).

Comment: @AmanDevrath If was helpful you can you accept this answer. ;-)